# const reference to a pointer can change the object

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

const references make sure you can't change the object you're referring to. For example:

```
int i = 1;
const int& ref = i;
ref = 42; // error, because of a const reference
```

But if you use a reference to a pointer or a `unique_ptr`, you can. Example:

```
class TinyClass {
public:
    int var = 1;
    void f1() { var = 42; }
};

std::unique_ptr<TinyClass> pointer(new TinyClass);
const std::unique_ptr<TinyClass>& constRef = pointer;
constRef->f1(); // no error
```

I assume this happens because the pointer itself wasn't changed. But this feels `misleading`, or like an easy mistake. Is there a simple way to declare a "real" const reference to a pointer? As in: makes sure the object itself is const.

edit: Assume that I can't just change the type of the unique_ptr. A real-world scenario would be that some objects are constructed in a `vector<unique_ptr<C>>` and some function gets a (const) reference to one of its elements.

Comment: Just use `std::unique_ptr<const TinyClass>`.

Comment: Even worse: you can change a referenced member variable of a const object.

Comment: That first snippet looks highly suspicious as well.  Try assigning anything to i.

Comment: Example of my claim: see [stacked-crooked](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/faaf194368b96975), it mean that const is not maintained over references/pointers

Comment: You could declare it like that if you had a builtin pointer, because builtin pointers have special rules of const propagation. Shared_ptr and other templates, sadly, cannot emulate this behaviour because the language doesn't have necessary mechanisms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `const` in `const std::unique_ptr<TinyClass>& constRef` guarantees that `constRef` will not point to another object once it set up. It has nothing to do with the object itself.

If you want to prevent changing the object itself:

```
std::unique_ptr<const TinyClass> ptr_to_const_object;
```

---

**Edit (after OP's edit):**

You can not do anything. Since there is a function which wants `const vector<unique_ptr<C>>&`, the function clearly tells you that it needs to play with the object inside the pointer (and even the pointer) but it does not need to change the vector items (like adding new item or deleting it).

Comment: Right, that would be the easy way. But in my real use case, the object is in a vector of unique_ptrs. I can't change that. A function is receiving a (const) reference to one of these objects. That's where I found that the const doesn't mean what it seems